# how to expand a div that contains half text and half image/photogallery?

Tags: jquery, html, css

i am trying to create a look alike "read more" div, i succed in creating it, but i have some problems when i try to make the main div ( with the read more button ) to be half text and half an image/photogallery ( it is like an article, to the left the text, to tthe right the image ) http://jsfiddle.net/nN3Uz/1/ . What should i change to this code to work propper my expectaction ?

html

```
<p id="title">Math</p>
<div class="expander" id="aspect">
                <div id="paragraf">
                Paragraph 2: Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est 
                laborum. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est Excepteur sint occaecat 
                cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in c
                ulpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est 
                </div>
        </div>
```

css

```
#title {
 border:1px solid #800000;
 width:1000px;
 background:#800000;
 color:#fff;
 margin-left:0px;
 font-size: 30px;
 }

#aspect {
width:1000px;
border: 1px solid #800000;
background:#fff;
box-shadow: 5px 5px 5px #494949;
padding-left:10px;
}

#paragraf {
margin-right:10px;
width:1000px;
}
```

Comment: I don't exactly understand what you are going for, where should the image be?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i tried using `<div>` but couldn't get it to work. if you want you can do it with tables.
http://jsfiddle.net/5cvtD/